# How to set up a ProgressBar for certain Interval - React Native(Should support IOS and Android)

Tags: react-native

In my app I need to show Progress Bar, that progress should be increase from 0 to 1 minutes or given Max time.

**Tried - ONE**

I tried a Progress Bar from 'react-native-paper'

```
 <ProgressBar progress={getTime} color={COLORS.grey} />
```

**Tried - TWO**

```
<Animated.View
            style={[
              {
                width: '100%',
                height: 5,
                borderRadius: 1,
                backgroundColor: COLORS.yellow,
              },
              {width: 25 + '%'},
            ]}
          />
```

But not able to get the output

Let me know to achieve this like in the Image below. Thank You
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For both solutions you tried you need to calculate the progress value for the component. In case of `react-native-paper` `ProgressBar`, this value should be in the range of 0-1. In case of you `Animated.View` solution, it should be in the range of 0-100.

To calculate this value, you need to know total time and how much time has passed. You can then simply divide `elapsedTime/totalTime` to get a value between 0-1.

If you need to track progress from 0 to 5 minutes, and want it to update every 1s:

```js
const useProgress = (maxTimeInSeconds = 300) => {
  const [elapsedTime, setElapsedTime] = useState(0);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      if (progress < 1) {
        setElapsedTime(t => t + 1);
      }
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setProgress(elapsedTime / maxTimeInSeconds);
  }, [elapsedTime]);

  return progress;
};
```

How to use, in a component:

```
const progress = useProgress();

return <ProgressBar progress={progress} />
```

Note: code not tested. This will start progress automatically when `useProgress` is called.

Comment: Since you have a `getTime` function call in your original question, I assumed you are already tracking the start time, how much time passed etc. - is that so? I'll update my answer with an example of tracking 1 minute progress.

Comment: What I want to do if I want it for Total time = 5 Minutes & Passed time = 1 Minute? Also how to start the Progress?

Comment: In my scenario Max time is always 5Mins. With a api call I'll get few values from I calculated the Remaining Time (or Passed Time). I want to know how to pass the value to the Progress view and how to start its progress

Comment: The progress does not run by itself. You have to constantly calculate the progress value and pass it to the ProgressBar component or use as width of your custom view.

For instance, if you want the progress to update every second, then you would need to use `setInterval(callback, 1000)` and inside `callback` calculate the new progress value.

Comment: Yes I can get your point. BTW can I see any sample code will be much helpful.

Comment: Thank You its working. Instead of 300 I passed the remaining time in MaxTime and calculate elapsed time instead of default 0.